# Can't format a date correctly while importing a csv into SAS

Tags: date, sas

I'm importing a csv file into SAS which contains a field which uses a word date format similar to worddatxw. but with letters after the day dates (e.g. 1st instead of 1):

```
Week_of_the_promotion
1st April 2013
1st April 2013
3rd April 2013
3rd April 2013
5th April 2013
```

I've got this far:

```
data work.leafletdata;
    infile "C:\rawdata.csv" 
    delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2;
    informat
        Week_of_the_promotion *weird informat?* Barcode $20. 
                StartDate mmddyy10.   EndDate mmddyy10. ;
    format
        Week_of_the_promotion *preferably date9.* Barcode $20. 
        StartDate date9.      EndDate   date9.  ;
    input 
        Week_of_the_promotion $  Barcode $  
                StartDate $              EndDate $  ;
run;
```

I cannot work out how to import this into SAS using proc import and while turning it into a usable date when within SAS .

I'm a SAS beginner, so please use layman's terms. Thanks! :)

Comment: How many different dates are there?

Answer (score 2):

This is one possible solution - breaking it up into "1st" "April" "2013", and then constructing a date from "April" "2013", finally using "1st" and the `intnx` function to advance that number of weeks.  You may need to adjust the call to `intnx` depending on how you define "1st week of April" (in the example that starts on 3/31 for example, if your company defines that as the week from 4/7 to 4/13 that's different, and if you need week to start on a different day of the week that's also an adjustment - look at the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212700.htm) for more information).

```
data have;
infile datalines truncover;
input @1 week_of_the_promotion $25.;
datalines;
1st April 2013 
1st April 2013 
3rd April 2013 
3rd April 2013 
5th April 2013
;;;;
run;

data want;
set have;
weeknum = compress(scan(week_of_the_promotion,1),,'kd');  *Note 1;
for_date = '01'||substr(scan(week_of_the_promotion,2),1,3)||
  scan(week_of_the_promotion,3);  *Note 2;
actual_date = intnx('week',input(for_date,date9.),weeknum-1,'b'); *Note 3;
format actual_date date9.;
put week_of_the_promotion= actual_date=;
run;
```

1. `Scan` separates the string into words by a delimiter, by default space, and returns the word you ask for (1, here).  `Compress` removes/keeps specific kinds of characters; here I use it to "keep" "digits".  So `scan` returns "1st" and then I tell it to keep only digits, so "1".
2. Here we use `scan` twice, to get "April" and "2013".  April is cut using substr to the first 3 characters, "Apr", because that is how SAS dates are most easily read.  Then we append the year to the end, and "01" to the beginning (for 1st day in ...).  This ends up being "01APR2013", which is then `input` using a date informat to a number (DDMONYYYY is SAS's default date in/format).
3. We use `intnx` here, which advances a date a certain number of date-intervals.  We are using "week" to advance it a certain number of weeks, and advancing the number stored in "weeknum" (from note 1) minus 1 (since week 1 = advance 0 weeks, week 2 = advance 1 week, etc.)  The "b" is "Beginning" of week (as opposed to 'end' or 'middle' or 'same').  "Week" is a default week starting on sunday; WEEK.2 would shift that forward two days to be weeks starting on Tuesdays, etc.

Comment: Ohh this is very helpful thanks! I found a similar method to yours which seems to convert it in one go:


new_week_of_promo = input(compress(compress(scan(week_of_the_promotion,1,' '),,'A')||substr(scan(week_of_the_promotion,2,' '),1,3)||scan(week_of_the_promotion,3,' ')), date9.);



but I'd like to implement this during the proc import. Is this possible or will I have to do it in a separate data step?

Thanks!

Comment: You certainly can combine all of these things together, I left them separate intentionally so you can see the pieces fit together (and there's very little extra overhead - just drop the extra variables and it doesn't matter anymore).

Comment: First off, you'd have to do it in a data step; you couldn't do it within `proc import`.  You could however do it in the input data step (as you posted above), that's a normal data step.  Second, I don't think that will actually work properly - that just uses the 'week' as a day, which is not the same as a week.

Comment: Just to satisfy my curiosity, is there some way to remove all instances of the words 'st', 'rd', 'nd' and 'th' so that sas will recognise the date as a worddatxw. format?

Comment: You could use TRANWRD, or a prx (regular expression), to do so.  Or you could remove it by doing a similar process to the above; scan the first word, compress out letters, then substr the remaining with substr(weekvar,4) and concatenate the compressed out first word to that substring.